# web.config forms authentication get all users

Tags: asp.net, forms, web-config, forms-authentication

I have a very simple asp.net application which I'm using forms authentication and storing each user's name / password in the web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="appNameAuth" path="/" loginUrl="l.aspx" protection="All" timeout="600">
        <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
          <user name="user1" password="pass1"/>
          <user name="user2" password="pass2"/>
          <user name="user3" password="pass3"/>   
        </credentials>
    </forms>
</authentication>
```

I'd like to simply be able to get all users, then bind them to a dropdownlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read web.config from code like that http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c2kcht0.aspx

I found that from msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.formsauthenticationconfiguration.credentials.aspx

```
FormsAuthenticationCredentials currentCredentials = formsAuthentication.Credentials;
StringBuilder credentials = new StringBuilder();
for (System.Int32 i = 0; i < currentCredentials.Users.Count; i++)
{
    credentials.Append("Name: " + currentCredentials.Users[i].Name + " Password: " + currentCredentials.Users[i].Password);
    credentials.Append(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had trouble doing this because it was pulling from my root web.config.

Comment: You should use this to open the form config of the request 's web.config :
`FormsAuthenticationConfiguration formsAuthentication= ((AuthenticationSection)WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~").GetSection("system.web/authentication")).Forms;`